# GLSurfaceView is not appearing until orientation change

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

I'm adding `GLSurfaceView` that is displaying the cam output from YUI renderer to `RelativeLayout`. I'm adding it on a callback from WebRTC SDK and it never gets rendered until phone is rotated. The code is pretty simple:

```
@Override
public void onLocalMediaCapture(final GLSurfaceView videoView) {
    mView.addView(videoView);
    mView.requestLayout();
    mView.requestRender();
}
```

I have it working by calling orientation change programmatically, right after adding the view, there and back:

```
mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        mView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }
        }, 0);
```

but it seems like overkill to me. Is there more elegant solution?

Comment: Is this an issue with the View not being added to the layout, or the Surface not appearing? Is the Surface configured in its default Z order, or on top? Are the SurfaceHolder callbacks firing?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! The content of GLSurfaceView (camera output) is not visible until phone is rotated. The surface doesn't have Z order configured because it's only child in `mView`. What callbacks do you mean, please explain.